# PHP GET sending 403 Error during search

Tags: php, apache

I have a search bar for my website that keeps sending weird error messages when I type certain things into the search.  Here is the page.  http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/searchmusic.php.  If I were to type in this "<><>" it sends me a message saying

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /searchmusic.php on this server.

I have tried to contact my hosting provider but they are of no help.  I htink that this might be a problem with apache, but I do not know for sure.  If anyone knows how to fix this error, any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: are you able to change the permissions on the file searchmusic.php? it seems your Apache user does not have access to that file.

Comment: I am able to change the permissions on my searchmusic file.  It is currently at 6 4 4 and it did not work at 7 5 5.

Comment: Any regular search works.  The error only occurs when I type in the above characters.

Comment: A can't seem to reproduce this problem. I see the requests when I type in `<><>`, but they all return 200. Tried including the `""` as well. Same result.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it would be ocurring on only my computer then?

Comment: This is the full error that i get. Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /searchmusic.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at www.pearlsquirrel.com Port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 403 errors may be thrown by security modules if they identify strange requests coming down the Apache pipeline. This is especially true if you are using a module like Mod Security.

In your case, sending a request with `<><>` may seem suspicious to the server, as it may interpret it as intending to find a vulnerability (a la SQL injection or what have you).

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there any way to have it stop showing me these messages?

Comment: If it's ModSecurity, check the log file for that module. you should be able to identify which security rule it was that triggered the error.

Comment: If you want to support these special characters, then you should also convert the search query to URL encoded characters. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript